# Splitting a string to an array using regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a function in Ruby which can take in a string and then split it based on certain criteria. This will be used to simulate grammar and create arbitrary word sequences. The strings exist as the following format:

How would I go about achieving this? I'm bit lost as to how to set up the regex and how to extract the items from the string into an array.

Comment: I see that you did get an answer to this question, but in the future it would be better to include your attempts to solve this on your own. That way, the answer can not only give you good code, but they can help you understand ruby better, and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "\n<start>\nYou <adj> <name> . ;\nMay <curse> . ;\n"

str.lines # Break on newlines
   .map{| l | l.gsub "\n", ''  } # remove trailing newlines
   .map{| l | l.gsub /\s*;$/, '' } # remove trailing spaces and ;
   .reject{| l | l.empty? }        # remove empty elements

=> ["<start>", "You <adj> <name> .", "May <curse> ."]
```

Comment: When I try to use this with the second example "\n<start>\nYou <adj> <name> . ;\n;\n" I get ["<start>", "You <adj> <name> ."] which is not accounting for the empty space that I should get ("" should be the last element in the array).

Comment: In that case, you should have an empty string at the beginning of the array as well because the string begins with "\n".

Comment: Is there any way to set up the regex to ignore the first "\n" only?